# Determining Causality and Time-Invariance of a system

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, homework, causality

Consider the following system:
$$y(t-1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x()u(-t) d $$
where $u(t)$ is the unit step function, which is zero for $t<0$ and equals $1$ for $t>0$.

$(1)$ Is the system causal? Why or why not?

> I think if $u(t)=0$ for all $t<0$. This means that $u(τ−t)=0$ for all $τ<t$ or, equivalently, for all $t>τ$ and the integrand is zero in range $({-\infty}, t)$.
> Therefore, we can show that:
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x()u(-t) d = \int_{t}^\infty x()u(-t) d =  \int_{t}^\infty x() d$$ So, the system is not causal! Am I right?!

$(2)$ Is the system time-invariant? Why or why not?

> Let $ s=t-1$
> $$y(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x()u(-s+1) d $$
> For invariance, we need to show output resulted from $x(s−s_o)$ = $y(s−s_o)$.
> $$y_1(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(-s_0)u(-s+1) d $$
> Now when I change of variable to $z=τ−s_o$, $τ=z+s_0$ , $dz=dτ$ it leads to:
> $$y_1(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(z)u(z+s_0-s+1) dz $$
> For $y(s-s_o)$ integral becomes:
> $$y_2(s-s_0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x()u(-s+1-s_0) d $$
> So it seems to time-variant system.
> **Update:I would appreciate if anyone can answer my question because it's not a homework anymore and yet I didn't find the answer.**

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Substitute $s = t-1$. That gets you the equations in a more standard form $y(s) = ...$ Then go through the same excercise.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning causality, your conclusion is correct. When you tried to investigate time-invariance you failed because you're not sufficiently careful when substituting variables. The first error occurred already when formulating the input-output equation for $y(t)$. Using $s=t-1$ means that $\tau-t$ becomes $\tau-(s+1)=\tau-s-1$, and hence you should obtain

$$y(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)u(\tau-s-1)d\tau\tag{1}$$

Now you're making the same mistake when you try to evaluate $y_2(s-s_0)$. Replacing $s$ by $s-s_0$ doesn't result in what you wrote down. If you do things right, you should see that the system is in fact time-invariant.

Time-invariance is also directly obvious from the original input-output equation, because it can be seen that the output signal is given by a convolution integral, and only LTI systems can be represented by convolution.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a little bit of explanation as to why you are calling $(1)$ a _convolution_ integral when, at first glance, it looks very much like a _correlation_ integral since the variable of integration $\tau$ has the same sign in both arguments in $(1)$ whereas in a _convolution_ integral, it should have opposite signsl.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I thought I'd initially leave that leap of imagination to the OP.